# How can I unwrap polys into a perfect square?

Tags: texturing, uv

first question here and yes, I already searched  and couldn't find anything for my case.

I'm trying to UV map a model I managed to get from a PS1 game as I'm doing a track conversion for rFactor 2, but the problem is that basically all the models use a perfect square projection (edge to edge on the UV) on it. My issue is that no matter what unwrap method I use (including modifying their settings), they never get unwrapped into a perfect square. If I could find a way to do that I would save a lot of manual work as like I said, all models use a square texture edge to edge.

EDIT: I found out that what I'm looking for is basically per face texture mapping but I can't find any way to do that

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Project From View (Bounds)?

Comment: That doesn't work as it's exactly what it says to be, a projection from view. Even zooming in doesn't change much and the issue is still there

Comment: Resetting UV coordinates will give you pefrect squares (U > Reset), but if faces are quads. Other than that try Smart UV Project

Comment: Mr Zak (and the answer below) solved my problem, the uv mapping becomes a perfect square and that will help me save a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem way back ;)

I used this addon:
http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/2015/05/addon-quad-unwrap.html

What I did was to unwrap all my quads that should share the same texture at once, used the addon to make all lines straight and then scaled the resulting grid so that one cell occupies the whole uv space, forcing the other cells outside thus making them exact uv copies of the first cell.

EDIT: It seems the author did not update the link he posted on blenderaddonlist. However in his youtue tutorial he posted a downloadlink in the description that still works ;)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcFEdK5TQv0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/li6nuop9c4omlih/wahooney_uv_quad_unwrap.py?dl=0

EDIT2: Triangles are a bitch. It does not work with them, since there is no way for the addon to know which way to follow to the next quad. So you would have to get rid of the triangles first. Unless the geometry is very complex the build in blender tri to quad function should be able to do it.

EDIT3: Feeling stupid right now ... using U -> Reset on the faces already does a per face mapping. Is that feature new ? I could swear the reset option was not there two years ago ;)

Comment: It is unfortunate that you are dealing with a triangulated mesh ... I do not know how well the addon handles triangles.

Comment: Damn I did not check the downloadlink ... it seems the author has abandoned it. Trying to do a search on my harddisk. Perhaps I can find it somewhere.